# Given two closed sets $A,B$, show that there exists some of them which contains all distances

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $A,B\subseteq[0,1)$ are closed, and that $A\cup B=[0,1)$.

Show that there exists a set $C\in\{A,B\}$ such that given an $x\in[0,1)$, $C$ contains two points $p$ and $q$ such that $|p-q|\in\{x,1-x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

For notational simplicity, note that for all $p, x \in [0, 1)$, setting $q := p + x \mod 1$ or $q := p - x \mod 1$ gives you $|p - q| \in \{x, 1-x\}$.

Suppose the result is not true. Let $x$ be a counterexample to the claim "$C = A$ works" and $y$ be a counterexample to the claim "$C = B$ works".

Suppose that there exists $p \in A \cap B$. Then $p + x \mod 1 \notin A$, thus $p + x \mod 1 \in B$. Then $p + x + y \mod 1 \notin B$, so $p + x + y \mod 1 \in A$. So $p + y \mod 1 = (p + x + y) - x \mod 1 \notin A$.

However, $p + y \mod 1 \notin B$ either since $p \in B$, contradicting $A \cup B = [0, 1)$. Thus no such $p$ exists, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. But then we have $[0, 1)$ as the union of the disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$, but this is impossible as $[0, 1)$ is connected.

Comment: @A.P. I'm not seeing it?

Comment: I understand now, thanks. Still, I think this answer would gain from a better exposition.